# How can I get my GIF to animate in my JavaScript game when it already works in my CSS background?

Tags: javascript, css, gif

I create a game in js with image of background in css, and image of hero also in png. Then I replace png with gif. In background it works but not in javascript (gif isn't animated). Somebody have idea why?

Somebody have idea why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.